# Late 70s space fighter diagrams, cheap paper

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, spaceship

I have little to provide other than a timeframe and some visual cues. This was a book I had in the late 70s, marketed to older kids. It was on cheap, dark paper (think of modern puzzle books) and I believe it was printed in landscape format. It had a collection of spaceships with diagrams pointing to different engines, weapons, etc. I don't think it was tied to any existing intellectual property--seems like it was probably targeted at Star Wars fans who'd go "Ooo, this is about space fighters."

Comment: Did it have science fiction or fantastical element? Or was it real-world?

Comment: @amflare Last I checked, space fighters were still science fiction -- though you never know what's in the X-37B cargo bay...

Comment: @amflare I am pretty sure most modern spacecraft do not carry weaponry and neither did most spacecraft in the 70s, save for SDI satellites. Usually, those would carry lasers or some other thing for destroying ICBMs or nukes while they were in flight.

Comment: No weaponized SDI satellites were ever deployed.

Comment: @amflare  space fighters will always remain science fiction, no matter what other space opera elements - FTL, force shields, ray guns, tractor & pressor beams, etc. etc. - become reality.  Space fighters don't make any logical sense.

Comment: @OrganicMarble though there were at least two weaponized Soviet spacecraft, the Almaz stations, and the Polyus(which failed to reach orbit)

Comment: @ZeissIkon, DarthVader, MAGolding - When OP explicitly says so instead of just vaguely insinuating amidst an attempt to describe a picture book and its marketing tactics, then I'll consider the question to be solidly on topic.

Comment: @amflare  I never said the question was off topic, instead I told you that space fighters will never be practical in a space opera setting.  Thus no matter how much else of space opera becomes reality space fighters will always remain science fiction or more accurately space fantasy.

Comment: @M.A.Golding The space fighter _does_ have a niche role in a realistic stellar scale civilisation although you are generally correct that their use in most fiction is not scientifically valid.

Comment: Not [Full Thrust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_Thrust) then? That's early 90's for first edition but have a look anyway.

Comment: Very much science fiction, of the pew-pew blaster sort. It's the kind of thing a publisher would rush out for a TV show or movie tie-in except that I don't think it WAS related to any famous IP.

Answer (score 3):

Could be the [Terran Trade Authority Handbook - Spacecraft 2000-2100 AD](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Spacecraft-2000-2100-D-Stewart-Cowley/dp/0890092117).
This was published in 1978 originally so the time-frame fits.

The book contains a lot of colour illustrations of spacecraft, which isn't mentioned in the question, although there are wire drawings of the ships as well, together with specifications of the craft.

There's a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=A8abMJhmvss) as well of the book being browsed, some of the illustrations made me go "ooooh! spaceships" although the OP mentions space fighters, but that might fit too

Comment: I thought of this as well, but the TTA books aren't in landscape format or printed on particularly cheap paper.

Comment: It wasn't that, though I remember the TTA Handbook well. I regret getting rid of most of that collection.